# Django runserver not working after installing redis for django channels

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

I am learning the [Django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) concepts and I am stuck when after [install the asgi_redis and the redis server](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#running-with-channels). If I have the CHANNEL_LAYERS configured for the **in-memory** backend. The server runs okay, and the web page is displayed.

However, if I run the server after configuring the CHANNEL_LAYERS for the **redis** backed, the web page is not displayed, and I get an error in the terminal:

```
Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2017-09-11 12:34:07,259 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-11 12:34:07,260 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-11 12:34:07,261 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-11 12:34:07,263 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2017-09-11 12:34:07,263 - INFO - server - Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel layer
2017-09-11 12:34:07,265 - INFO - server - Listening on endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2017-09-11 12:34:07,267 - ERROR - server - Error trying to receive messages: unknown command 'EVALSHA'
2017-09-11 12:34:07,268 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-11 12:34:12,270 - ERROR - server - Error trying to receive messages: unknown command 'EVALSHA'
2017-09-11 12:34:17,272 - ERROR - server - Error trying to receive messages: unknown command 'EVALSHA'
```

I have installed the **asgi_redis** in my virtualenv, and also installed Redis server. What am I doing wrong here?

Here are the useful versions that I am using:

- channels==1.1.6
- asgi-redis==1.4.2
- daphne==1.3.0
- Django==1.11.5

Comment: EVALSHA is available since Redis 2.6.0, what version of redis do you have ? https://redis.io/commands/evalsha

Comment: @jpic Yes, i think just running `sudo apt-get install redis-server` installs the  old version of redis, instead of the latest one.